# Error closing Word doc: "The message filter indicated that the application is busy."

Tags: c#, asp.net, com-interop

I'm using Microsoft Interop to save a Word Doc as an HTML file, and I'm getting this error when I try to close the document:

> **The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))**

Here's my code:

```
// word interop setting
object visible = true;
object readOnly = true;
object missing = Type.Missing;
object saveChanges = true;
object htmlFile = (object)Server.MapPath(@"worddoc.html");
object fileType = 
  (object)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatFilteredHTML;       

// open document
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordApp =
  new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc =
  wordApp.Documents.Open(ref url, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref  missing, ref  visible, ref missing, ref missing,
       ref missing, ref missing);

try
{                           
    // save the file                 
    wordDoc.SaveAs(ref htmlFile, ref fileType, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
        ref missing, ref missing);
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    saveChanges = false;
}
finally
{
    wordDoc.Close(ref saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing); // ERROR HERE
    wordApp.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
    wordDoc = null;
    wordApp = null;
}
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It works correctly when I test it, are you sure your html file path is correct? I did a console app that just saves both files locally and it works with no problems. Perhaps you are running into a security issue in terms of the location where you are attempting to save?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't anything wrong with your code. The problem is you are running it in an unsupported configuration, and the behaviour of office is undefined in this situation (running under asp.net)

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

For more info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

You can however use the [VSTO server document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.serverdocument.aspx) class to work with office documents without starting Office.

Comment: This should be a comment imo

Comment: @kd7 my answer is too long by 81 characters

Comment: Hi, I was facing the same problem with Excel to PDF conversion (via Office Interop assemblies). I eventually implemented the solution mentioned here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in.aspx.
Please note that the coRegisterMessageFilter() API will work ONLY from STA threads and will fails on MTA threads. So In case you cannot change the apartment type o your current client thread - You will need to start a new one (STA!) and wait for it to finish (thread.Join()).