# Got "The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))" error

Tags: asp.net

[The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC_E_SERVERCALL_RETRYLATER))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL6wb.png)

Comment: You should always give some context to your question by showing us some code that you have written.

Comment: This is not how you ask a question. Read [ask]. Also, don't do Office Interop on a web server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to solve The message filter indicated that the application is busy. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010A (RPC\_E\_SERVERCALL\_RETRYLATER)) asp.net mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872332/how-to-solve-the-message-filter-indicated-that-the-application-is-busy-excepti)

Answer (score 0):

You have a Word dialog that is trying to display, adjust your code to automate the dismissal of dialog boxes.